# How to queue some code to be executed at next cycle under firemonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Under firemonkey, When i want to execute some code after the current "cycle", I do like this :

```
 TThread.createAnonymousThread(
   procedure
   begin
     TThread.queue(nil,
       procedure
       begin
         domycode
       end);
   end).start;
```

because if we are in the mainThread, then TThread.queue will execute the code immediatly. I m curious if their is not another way to do this than using a thread ?

Comment: I think the Application.OnIdle event would solve that, but if your code *can* run in a background thread without problems, then that would probably be preferred.

Comment: too complicated to move my code in OnIdle :( i just want to get out of the current sync cycle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In 10.2 Tokyo, a new [`TThread.ForceQueue()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TThread.ForceQueue) method was added to address [RSP-15427](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-15427) (Add an option to let TThread.Queue() run asynchronously when called by the main UI thread):

```
TThread.ForceQueue(nil,
  procedure
  begin
    domycode
  end
);
```

No thread is needed.

Prior to Tokyo, you would have to re-write the code if you don't want to use an anonymous thread to call `TThread.Queue()`. For instance, you could post yourself a delayed message with [`PostMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) or [`PostThreadMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644946.aspx), and then do the work in the message handler.  Or use the [`TApplication(Events).OnIdle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.OnIdle) event, like GolezTrol suggested.